# Drop and recreate old tables in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-syncdb

I'm in the initial phase of development, and the models are changing around quite a lot.
I have to keep dropping the old tables and then performing a "syncdb"

While I appreciate the reason why syncdb does not alter the old tables,

### Is it possible (or is there any other alternative) to drop the old tables automatically and then run syncdb?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175993/what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-data-in-django.

Comment: @Pramod It does look like it, but those answers are from 4 years ago. Could it be that there is a better/easier solution now?

Comment: I don't think so. I've used South and it has worked well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way I typically do this is at the database level.  If, for example, you were using postgres, and just wanted to blow away the whole DB to start fresh, you could do:

```
dropdb -U postgres "dbname"
createdb -U postgres -O "db_user" "db_name"
```

For long projects I'm working on, I use a [fabfile](http://fabfile.org) for automating tasks like the above, as well as grabbing the latest database from my production server, and overwriting my local development db.

Also, related is database "migration", which becomes a requirement when you change code after it's been running in production a while. A lot of people / apps use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), but I prefer [Nashvegas](http://paltman.com/2009/02/24/nashvegas-a-simple-django-migration-tool/) for my sites.

With Nashvegas, I would create a 0001_add_field_blah.sql file which contained my raw SQL commands for altering the db.  eg:

```
ALTER TABLE myapp_model RENAME COLUMN first_name TO given_name;
```

Comment: would you mind sharing your fabfile? I am new to Python, would be a good learning point.
Also, a question about Fab: would the same commands work in Windows shell as well as Linux shell? Or have I misunderstood its use?

Comment: Alas, my fabfile has grown rather organically, and is a little untidy.  Not much use for anyone but the creator.  I just discovered a [django-fabdeploy-plus](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-fabdeploy-plus/0.4) project that might be helpful to you, though.

Comment: I think I will go with South. Seems hassle-free to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `python manage.py reset <app>`. I don't think there's a way to do it project-wide though.

Comment: I could not find this in the Django docs... is this supported in 1.4?

Comment: I'm using it in 1.3. You're right that it disappeared from the 1.4 docs though... you could try `python manage.py` which lists the supported commands. In 1.3, `reset <app>` drops and creates tables for the specified apps(s)