# django-sitetree how to migrate data to production server

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration, django-sitetree

I'm using **south** to migrate schemes to production. Also I'm using the **django-sitetree** module to show the menu in my site.

There is no problem with schema migration by using commands:

```
./manage.py schemamigration myApp --freeze sitetree --auto
./manage.py migrate myApp
```

However when I'm trying to migrate the sitetree data by command:

```
./manage.py datamigration myApp "new_version" --freeze sitetree
```

it doesn't generate any of created sitetree elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some research and thanks to this sources: [Altering database tables in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991/altering-database-tables-in-django) and [Fixtures and initial data](http://djangotricks.blogspot.com.ar/2008/09/gotchas-about-fixtures-for-initial-data.html) blog, it seems that the better way to pass the menu data by using initial_data.json file with fixtures.

1. Create "fixtures" folder inside your App folder.
2. Run `./manage.py dumpdata --format=json --indent=4 sitetree > APP_PATH/fixtures/initial_data.json` You can add more app to the command if you wish their data to be migrated to other environments.
3. The saved data to `fixtures/initial_data.json` will be always inserted/replaced by running `./manage.py syncdb` Remember that the data will be replaced if it already exists in DB, it means that you should not dump the dynamic data.

There is the other way to migrate the sitetree using [sitetree management command](https://django-sitetree.readthedocs.org/en/latest/management.html)

```
# Dump...
python manage.py sitetreedump > treedump.json
# Restore...
python manage.py sitetreeload --mode=replace treedump.json
```

Thank you to [idle-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308265/idle-sign) for this link

Comment: Thank you @idlesign, I've recently edited my answer and added your link.